# Select the record which is appeared most in a table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am working with `WPF` application and using `Entity Framework`. I have a table in which a Column contains some values which appear more than once. I want to get the record or value that appears most and then the second and then the third.
as in the following table the the `ProductID = 1` value is appearing more than once and like this some other `ProductID` can appear more then once. i want to know which ID appeared more times and which appeared second most and so on ?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far???  SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: I would think SQL Ranking would work, but there is a lot of information missing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use count(*) and group by ProductID

```
select Top 3 ProductID, count(*)
from my_table  
group by ProductID
order by  count(*) DESC
```

and you can use TOP 3 for get the firsts 3 top rows

if you want all

```
select ProductID, count(*)
from my_table  
group by ProductID
order by  count(*) DESC
```

Comment: i want to know how many times `1` is appearing and how many times `2` or so on .. and which one is appearing most ?

Comment: @Hammas_stack2 Add your expected output to your question.  Scais answer does what you seem to want - returns the top 3 most common products and their counts.

Comment: @Hammas_stack2   .. the query return  the most 3 frequent productID  .. answer upsated  for all the product count  in descending order

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
select productID, Count(*) from table_name group by productID;
```

it will give you productID with its count.